# swap two columns of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to swap two columns in matlab such that it can be done in one statement? I know `A(:,[i,j])=A(:,[j,i])` can do the job. But I'd like it to be in the form `swap_column(A, i, j)`. Is there such a built-in or simple operations using only built-in's?

Comment: what's wrong with A(:,[i,j])=A(:,[j,i])? It is fast and elegant.

Comment: Why do you need a `builtin` function? What about `A(:,[i,j])=A(:,[j,i])` is insufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

1. If you agree to have `A=swap_cols(A,i,j);` then you simply write a function

   `function A = swap_cols(A,i,j)
   assert( i > 0 && i < size(A,2) && j > 0 && j < size(A,2) );
   A(:,[i j]) = A(:,[j i]);`
2. If you want an "operator"-like function that does not have an output argument, then you may want to have something like:

   `function swap_cols(Astr,i,j)
   m = evalin('caller', sprintf('size(%s,2);', Astr));
   assert( i > 0 && i < m && j > 0 && j < m );
   evalin('caller', sprintf('%s(:,[%d %d] = %s(:,[%d,%d]);', Astr, j, i, Astr, i, j) );`

You call this function with the **name** of the matrix, not the matrix itself:

> swap_cols( 'A', i, j );

Cheers!

Comment: +1. I like the innovative the string-accepting function, although it's _really_ an overkill.

Comment: @EitanT an overkill would be using `inputname` instead of `Astr` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

permute does the job in Matlab

```
A = permute(A,[2 1]);
```